# How to truncate characters over a certain length in C?

Tags: c, loops, char, getchar, putchar

I'm working on a C program that takes in an input of lines of text, and return it by printing only 40 characters each.
So far, I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char input = getchar();
    int numChar;
    int total;

    while ((input != EOF) && (input != '\n')) {
        ++numChar;
        if (numChar > 40) {
            printf("\n");
            ++total;
            numChar = 0;
        }
        putchar(input);
        input = getchar();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Just updated my post with a new draft I have. For this attempt I am trying to print each character as it takes each input but if the character count is over 40, to make a new line. But, I don't get an output as expected.

Comment: If string after 40th position is ignored: `returnInput[40] = 0;  printf( "%s\n", returnInput );`

Comment: `int numChar;` -> `int numChar = 0;` and same for `total`.

Comment: @Sarah Why is the first outputted line shorter than the second outputted line?

Comment: `input` needs to be an `int` not a `char` (because `EOF` is a value that's not the same as any `char`).

Comment: @psmears on common systems where EOF is -1 and char is signed, EOF is the same value as a char .   It needs to be `int` because getchar returns an int value that is out of range for `char` .

Comment: @M.M It is not out of the range for char because there used the integer promotions.:) It is only out of the range when the type char behaves as the type unsigned char.

Comment: The description is somewhat ambiguous, do you mean to print at most 40 characters for each line of input? Or do you want this to stop at the first line? Or do you want to break lines longer than 40 characters into smaller chunks?

Answer (score 2):

You are using two uninitialized variables

```
int numChar;
int total;
```

So the program has undefined behavior.

Moreover the accumulated value of the variable `total` is not used in the program.

And the variable `input` has to be declared as having the type `int`.

Pay attention to that the last outputted substring can contain less than 40 characters. In this case you need to call

```
putchar( '\n' );
```

also after the loop.

Using your approach with inputting characters by means of the function `getchar` the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t LINE_LENGTH = 40;
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; )
    {
        putchar( c );

        if ( ++count % LINE_LENGTH == 0 )
        {
            putchar( '\n' );
            count = 0;
        }

    }

    if ( count % LINE_LENGTH != 0 ) putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to input the string shown in your question then the output will be

```
This line is soooooooooooooooooo looooou
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooong!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if thats whats you're asking. Basically every 40 characters, a `newline` character is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if (i++ < 40)
    {
      putchar(c);
    }
    else if (i++ > 40 && c !='\n')
    {
      i = 1;
      printf("\n%c",c);
    }
    if (c == '\n')
    {
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Your code seem to work fine **if** you were to initiliaze `numChar` `-->` `numChar = 0` and `total` `-->` `total = 0`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Seems like I forgot to initialize haha.

Answer (score 0):

Actually strings are sequences of chars terminated by a null char '\0', so strings are arrays of chars.

You can easily iterate over the string untill you encounter the null char and on every iteration you print the current char and if the character index is a multiple of 40 you print a new line char, in this way every 40 character you split the string.

So here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LENGHT 200

int main () {
    char input[MAX_LENGHT];
    fgets(input, MAX_LENGHT, stdin);
    
    int index = 0;
    while (input[index++] != '\0') {
        putchar(input[index]);
        if (index % 40 == 0) {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char c;

    for(int i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        
        if( !(i % 40) ) puts("");
        
        putchar(c);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or if you want to avoid starting on a newline , just change the `if` to

```
if( i && !(i % 40) ) puts("");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- `numChars` and `total` are uninitialized, you get undefined behavior.
- you only handle the first line of text as you stop when you read a newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int pos = 0, c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            putchar(c);
            pos = 0;
        } else
        if (pos < 40) {
            putchar(c);
            pos++;
        } else {
            // ignore the character beyond the first 40
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the question  The input is granted to be a single line of text and the OP wants to print the input in a maximum-40-characters-per-line format

Comment: @Davide: the OP's question is ambiguous: *a C program that takes in an input of lines of text, and return it by printing only 40 characters each*. I interpret the plural in *lines* and the word *each* to mean: a C program that prints at most 40 characters of each line of input. I may be wrong, let's ask the OP.

Comment: @Davide: *truncate* is usually interpreted to mean *discard the excess*, but the OP may have meant to *break* or *wrap* lines longer than 40 characters and the code does indeed attempt to do that.

Comment: Yes the question is indeed ambiguous. But if you look at the OP's code, he stops to print when a newline is found (so he assumes the input is a single line) and he prints a newline every 40 characters

Comment: @Davide: Yes she does that, but classic wisdom says: *If the code and the comments disagree then both are probably wrong* :)

Comment: Ahaha fair enough